# How to increase the size of upload_file form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

im having a trouble, ive a form and on this form have a file upload field, inside of this field has the name of uploaded files (im gonna put a screenshot to show this part), but if i upload more thanb 3 images the line breaks and filenames doesnt align in the same line, i though a possible fix which is increase the size of the field or something else (idk yet), so if you guys could help me i appreciate it alot!

***IMG of the field overloaded:***

[image: img of the field overloaded]

***Code:***

```
<div class="col-4">
      <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, placeholder: "Choose file", class: 'file-upload-field' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increase the column value for increasing the width of upload field.
If you don't want to change col-4 then place your field inside a container, give it a class and add a css property of overflow:hidden to it.

```
<style>
.custom-file{
   overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="col-4">
            <div class="custom-file">
             <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true, placeholder: "Choose file", class: 'file-upload-field' %>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did the overflow: hidden in the css but the field was very small now, should I include the css properties inside the custom-file class?

Comment: yes add css property on container named custom-file,you can find the code above.It uses your dynamic field inside a container and you need to add property to container not the field.

Comment: i'm putting the css properties (height and width) inside the custom-file class but it doesn't change anything in the field

Comment: For changing field width because it is inside col-4 that is restricting it.You need to change col-4 to lets say col-6 or value greater than 4.This will allow your field to increase its width.

Comment: Sorry, idk whats happening but the field still without change, maybe i didnt mention this col-4 container its inside of row t-5 container too, does it influence something?

Comment: yes could be issue, might some parent container restricting it, can you share your link where i can see the result and suggest you.